# Parameter referenced in sql is an out parameter exception thrown

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a named raw ad-hoc query and execute with an output parameter. I am adding both input and output parameters to the command object properly i believe. I am trying to understand that the parsing that goes on for output parameters in Npgsql and why it is failing. Any Ideas.. I have tried to provide some info here.. Let me know if you can help or would need additional info. I think this should be a straightforward use case to insert some data and get some scalar return vals back from a named query using out params

Postgres

```
BEGIN

 SELECT nextval('Role_seq') into :v_roleId;

  INSERT INTO Role (roleId, organizationId, name, notes, locked, roleTypeId, rightsFlags)
  VALUES (:v_roleId, :v_organizationId, :v_name, :v_notes, :v_locked, :v_roleTypeId, :v_rightsFlags);

END;
```

SQL Server

```
    INSERT INTO Role (organizationId, name, notes, locked, roleTypeId, rightsFlags)
VALUES (@organizationId, @name, @notes, @locked, @roleTypeId, @rightsFlags)
SELECT @roleId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Oracle

```
BEGIN
  SELECT Role_roleId_SEQ.NEXTVAL into :v_roleId FROM DUAL;

  INSERT INTO Role (roleId, organizationId, name, notes, locked, roleTypeId, rightsFlags)
  VALUES (:v_roleId, :v_organizationId, :v_name, :v_notes, :v_locked, :v_roleTypeId, :v_rightsFlags);
END;
```

I am binding all the parameters properly and this code works on all platforms(providers) except Postgres where some query parsing is failing. Here is how i am adding the params.

```
   dsh.AddNQParameter(cmd, "roleId", ParameterDirection.Output, (object)DBNull.Value, "Int", "Int32", "Integer");
            dsh.AddNQParameter(cmd, "organizationId", ParameterDirection.Input, organizationId ?? (object)DBNull.Value, "Int", "Int32", "Integer");
            dsh.AddNQParameter(cmd, "name", ParameterDirection.Input, name ?? (object)DBNull.Value, "VarChar", "Varchar2", "Varchar");
            dsh.AddNQParameter(cmd, "notes", ParameterDirection.Input, notes ?? (object)DBNull.Value, "VarChar", "Varchar2", "Varchar");
            dsh.AddNQParameter(cmd, "locked", ParameterDirection.Input, locked ?? (object)DBNull.Value, "Bit", "Byte", "Boolean");
            dsh.AddNQParameter(cmd, "roleTypeId", ParameterDirection.Input, roleTypeId ?? (object)DBNull.Value, "Int", "Int32", "Integer");
            dsh.AddNQParameter(cmd, "rightsFlags", ParameterDirection.Input, rightsFlags ?? (object)DBNull.Value, "Image", "Blob", "Bytea");
```

Stack Trace for Postgres

```
Result StackTrace:  
at Npgsql.SqlQueryParser.ParseRawQuery(String sql, Boolean standardConformantStrings, NpgsqlParameterCollection parameters, List`1 statements)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ProcessRawQuery()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<Execute>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteNonQuery>d__84.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at LandisGyr.Data.Helper.ExecuteNonQueryReturnInt(DbCommand cmd, String name) in D:\tfs\cc\Command Center\Components\LGDALGenerator\Main\LG.Data.Core\Foundation\Helper.cs:line 76
   at DAL_Generator_Test.Data.NamedQueries.Test.NamedQueriesTest.InsRole(DbCommand cmd, Nullable`1 organizationId, String name, String notes, Nullable`1 locked, Nullable`1 roleTypeId, Byte[] rightsFlags, Nullable`1& roleId) in D:\tfs\cc\Command Center\Components\LGDALGenerator\Main\DAL Generator Test\Data\NamedQueries\NamedQueries.Test.Designer.cs:line 985
   at DAL_Generator_Test.SqlServerTests.NamedQueriesPostgresTests.Execute_NonQuery_Test_Using_DbCommand() in D:\tfs\cc\Command Center\Components\LGDALGenerator\Main\DAL Generator Test\PostgresTests\NamedQueriesPostgresTests.cs:line 90
Result Message: 
Test method DAL_Generator_Test.SqlServerTests.NamedQueriesPostgresTests.Execute_NonQuery_Test_Using_DbCommand threw exception: 
System.Exception: Parameter ':v_roleId' referenced in SQL but is an out-only parameter
```

Code Sample to repro the problem

```
using Npgsql;
using NpgsqlTypes;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostgresTest"].ConnectionString;

            // create a table as follows
            /*
             * CREATE TABLE  role
(
    roleid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('role_seq'::regclass),
    name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    notes character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    organizationid integer NOT NULL,
    roletypeid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    locked boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    rightsflags bytea
)
             */
            using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectString))
            {

                con.Open();

                using (DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"BEGIN

 SELECT nextval('Role_seq') into: v_roleId;

                    INSERT INTO Role(roleId, organizationId, name, notes, locked, roleTypeId, rightsFlags)
  VALUES(:v_roleId, :v_organizationId, :v_name, :v_notes, :v_locked, :v_roleTypeId, :v_rightsFlags);

                    END;";

                    var roleIdParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_roleId", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
                    roleIdParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(roleIdParam);

                    var orgParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_organizationId", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
                    orgParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    orgParam.Value = 1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(orgParam);

                    var nameParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_name", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
                    nameParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    nameParam.Value = "test role";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(nameParam);

                    var lockedParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_locked", NpgsqlDbType.Boolean);
                    lockedParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    lockedParam.Value = false;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(lockedParam);


                    var roleTypeIdParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_roleTypeId", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
                    roleTypeIdParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    roleTypeIdParam.Value = 1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(roleTypeIdParam);


                    var rightsFlagsParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_rightsFlags", NpgsqlDbType.Bytea);
                    rightsFlagsParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    rightsFlagsParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(rightsFlagsParam);


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    object roleId = cmd.Parameters[":v_roleId"].Value;

                    Console.WriteLine($"role id is {roleId}");

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");

                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, I can see `:v_roleId` in the SQL statement, but not in your code populating parameters (there's only `roleId` there)...

Comment: Yes. I have some code where in the :v_  param prefix has been added as follows                     var npgsqlParam = new NpgsqlParameter(string.Format(":{0}{1}", paramName.StartsWith(PostgresParameterPrefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ? "" : PostgresParameterPrefix, paramName.ToLower()), dbSpecificTypesMap[dbSpecificType]);
                    npgsqlParam.Direction = direction;
                    npgsqlParam.Value = paramValue;
                    ocmd.Parameters.Add(npgsqlParam);

Comment: :v_ is a param prefix that my postgres provider abstraction is adding and that is why you don't see it there.

Comment: This is unclear, because you show too little relevant code. What are these things that start with `:`?

Comment: I understand. Let me write a small sample application and post that code. This code will remove any framework abstraction around Npgsql. For now please think of : as some param prefix to indicate it is a bindable param

Comment: I also want to know if the Npgsql provider is attaching any special parsing to the : in the bind variables/param prefixes

Comment: Please look through the code sample posted and let me know if you can see the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I have read the documentation on "In / Out Parameters". 
https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html

I did a test that returned the value of the sequence, in a very similar case.

Note that you do not set the output parameter in the SQL statement. 
`INSERT INTO x RETURNING x.roleId`<s>INTO :roleId</s>

Sample code

```
using Npgsql;
using NpgsqlTypes;
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostgresTest"].ConnectionString;

            using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectString))
            {

                con.Open();

                using (DbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Role(roleId, organizationId, name, notes, locked, roleTypeId, rightsFlags)
  VALUES(nextval('Role_seq'), :v_organizationId, :v_name, :v_notes, :v_locked, :v_roleTypeId, :v_rightsFlags) RETURNING roleId";

                    var orgParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_organizationId", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
                    orgParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    orgParam.Value = 1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(orgParam);

                    var nameParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_name", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
                    nameParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    nameParam.Value = "test role";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(nameParam);

                    var lockedParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_locked", NpgsqlDbType.Boolean);
                    lockedParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    lockedParam.Value = false;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(lockedParam);


                    var roleTypeIdParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_roleTypeId", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
                    roleTypeIdParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    roleTypeIdParam.Value = 1;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(roleTypeIdParam);


                    var rightsFlagsParam = new NpgsqlParameter(":v_rightsFlags", NpgsqlDbType.Bytea);
                    rightsFlagsParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;
                    rightsFlagsParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(rightsFlagsParam);


                    var roleIdParam = new NpgsqlParameter("Returning_roleIdParam", NpgsqlDbType.Integer);
                    roleIdParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(roleIdParam);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    object roleId = cmd.Parameters["Returning_roleIdParam"].Value;

                    Console.WriteLine($"role id is {roleId}");

                    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");

                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```